# how do i display correct and incorrect answer when user click on radio buttons

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, database

I'm working on a small quiz web application I want to display correct or incorrect answers whenever the user's click on a radio button.

The Problem is that Ajax shows the Incorrect Option in AnswerResult Column Water and is correct and wrong. I want whenever if and is correct than function should be displayed correct in AnswerResult Column and if and is wrong than function should be displayed incorrect in AnswerResult Column

**Html Form**

```
<div id='question<?php echo $i;?>' class='cont'>
  <h3>Question No  <?php echo $i?></h3><br>
  <p class='questions' id="qname<?php echo $i;?>"><?php echo $result['question'];?></p>

  <h3>Choose Answer:</h3><br>
    <input type="radio" value="A" class='radioButton radioButton<?php echo $result['que_id'];?>' name='<?php echo $result['que_id'];?>'/><?php echo $result['optionA'];?> <br/>
    <input type="radio" value="B" class='radioButton radioButton<?php echo $result['que_id'];?>' name='<?php echo $result['que_id'];?>'/><?php echo $result['optionB'];?><br/>
    <input type="radio" value="C" class='radioButton radioButton<?php echo $result['que_id'];?>' name='<?php echo $result['que_id'];?>'/><?php echo $result['optionC'];?><br/>
    <input type="radio" value="D" class='radioButton radioButton<?php echo $result['que_id'];?>' name='<?php echo $result['que_id'];?>'/><?php echo $result['optionD'];?><br/>
    <input type="radio" checked='checked' style='display:none' value="5" class='radioButton radioButton<?php echo $result['que_id'];?>' name='<?php echo $result['que_id'];?>'/><br/>
    <button disabled="disabled" id='<?php echo $i;?>' class='mc-btn btn-style-6 nextButton<?php echo $result['que_id'];?>' type='button'>Next</button>
</div>     

<h4 class="title-sb sm bold">

  Correct Answer:
  <span class="AnswerResult"></span>
```

**Ajax Request Checking Answers**

```
   $('body').on('click', '.radioButton', function(){

var selected_answer = $(this).val();
var question_id = $(this).attr('name');

postData = 'ajaxrequest=submit_question&question_id='+question_id+'&selected_answer='+selected_answer;

 $.ajax
 ({
   data: postData,
   type:'POST',
   url: "start-quiz.php",
   dataType : 'html',
   cache : false,


   success: function(data) {
        if(data.correct == 'true')
        {   
            $('.AnswerResult').html("Correct");
            console.log('correct');
        }else {
            $('.AnswerResult').html("Incorrect");
            console.log('incorrect');
        }
            $('input.radioButton'+question_id).disabled(true);
            $('.nextButton'+question_id).disabled(false);

         }
        });
       });
```

**Php Sql Query Get Answer Based On Ajax Request**

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['ajaxrequest']) && $_REQUEST['ajaxrequest'])
{
    $return_data = array();
    switch(strtolower($_REQUEST['ajaxrequest']))
    {

        case 'submit_question':

            $question_id = (int)$_POST['question_id'];
            $sel_answer = $_POST['selected_answer'];
            $return_data['correct'] = false;

            // Check database if answer is correct or wrong
            $ans = mysql_query("select rightans from  question_bank where que_id='$question_id'")or die("select  correct  ans");
            //$getans=mysql_query($ans) ;
            $showans=mysql_fetch_row($ans);
            $db_answer = $showans['rightans']; 

            if($sel_answer == $db_answer)
                $return_data['correct'] = true;

            break;

    }

    echo json_encode($return_data);
    die();
}
```

Problem AnswerResult Column Is Showing Incorrect When Ajax Request Post

Comment: why you deleted yesterday's question and again opened a newer one for the same issue?

Comment: you have `<span class="AnswerResult"></span>`; so you need `$('.AnswerResult').html(` instead of `$('#AnswerResult').html(` as you have `class` and not the `id`

Comment: @vijayP yesterday i didn't get solution and also i have try with `class` but still same issue

Comment: can you put `console.log(typeof data.correct + " - "+data.correct)` just before `if(data.correct == 'true')` and tell me what you see there?

Comment: @FarhanDharsi, instead of radio button click maybe you can fire ajax on  radio button check change event. like `$("#r1, #r2, #r3, #r4").change(function () {});`

Comment: there is an problem with your ajax also : **dataType:'html'** but from backend your returning JSON object...!!!

Comment: @vijayP ajax is showing `undefined - undefined  incorrect` when i clicked in all radio buttons?

Comment: this is because you used `dataType:'html'` try with my answer OR change `dataType:'json'` in your exist code.

Comment: ok..so can you remove `dataType:` option from your ajax code as suggested by Soni Vimal. Let the browser handle incoming data type.

Comment: @vijayP after using Soni Vimal ajax function code still <span class="AnswerResult"></span> empty

Comment: do `console.log(data)` at very first line in success handler

Comment: @vijayP i have try `success: function(data) {console.log(data);` but empty?

Comment: @vijayP do u have skype id?

Comment: debug you PHP code is it working proper or not. put `echo "<pre>";print_r($return_data);exit;` before `echo json_encode($return_data);` and check whether the output array is empty or not?

Comment: ok wait let me check it out

Comment: @vijayP `Array([correct] => )` is empty?

Comment: means, your SQL Query having issue :-) debug in same way as I suggest above for return Array...!!! and resolved it. .

Comment: **MySql** is deprecated try to use **`mysqli`**

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133853/discussion-between-farhan-dharsi-and-soni-vimal).

Comment: @vijayP you got any solution still facing same issue?

Comment: @FarhanDharsi - sorry. I am not expert in PHP. So can't help you much here.

Answer (score 0):

> **Edit** Corrected ajax function.

```
$(document).on('change', '.radioButton', function(){
  var selected_answer = $(this).val();
  var question_id = $(this).attr('name');

  postData = 'ajaxrequest=submit_question&question_id='+question_id+'&selected_answer='+selected_answer;

  $.ajax
  ({
    url: "start-quiz.php",
    data: postData,
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    processData: false,
    contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    cache : false,
    success: function(data) {
      console.log(data);
      if (typeof (data.correct) !== 'undefined' && (data.correct != "" || data.Key != null)){
      var response = (data.correct == 'true')?"Correct":"Incorrect";
      //(data.correct == true)?"Correct":"Incorrect"
      $('.AnswerResult').html(response);
      $('input.radioButton'+question_id).disabled(true);  
      $('.nextButton'+question_id).disabled(false);
     }



    }
  });
 });
```

Comment: brother `<span class="AnswerResult"></span>` still empty

Comment: soni vimal do you have skype id?

Comment: I Have TeamViewer... have you?

Comment: via TeamViewer take your PC as an remote and will be able to resolve your issue. So can you download and install it?

Answer (score 0):

Please change datatype in ajax call :

from

```
dataType : 'html',
```

to

```
dataType : 'json',
```

and try console.log(data[0]);

and see what you get.

Comment: brother i have try Soni Vimal ajax function but still same issue

Comment: what data you get in data[0]